# Navigation property values not added to entity

Tags: asp.net-web-api, odata, breeze

I've a WebAPI OData v3 (5.6.3) service (without EF) which I call from breeze using server side metadata. Unfortunately I cannot get navigation properties to load correctly in breeze.

The model is defined as following:

```
    public class ParentItem
    {
        private readonly List<ChildItem> childItems = new List<ChildItem>();

        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<ChildItem> ChildItems
        {
            get
            {
                return this.childItems;
            }
        }

        #endregion
    }

    public class ChildItem
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("ParentItem")]
        public int? ParentItemId { get; set; }

        public virtual ParentItem ParentItem { get; set; }
   }
```

These are the metadata generated by the server:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<edmx:Edmx Version="1.0" xmlns:edmx="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/06/edmx">
  <edmx:DataServices m:DataServiceVersion="3.0" m:MaxDataServiceVersion="3.0" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata">
    <Schema Namespace="Solutions2Share.Solutions.MeetingManagerWeb.Models" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/11/edm">
      <EntityType Name="ParentItem">
        <Key>
          <PropertyRef Name="Id" />
        </Key>
        <Property Name="Id" Type="Edm.Int32" Nullable="false" />
        <NavigationProperty Name="ChildItems" Relationship="MyNamespace_ChildItem_ChildItemsPartner" ToRole="ChildItems" FromRole="ChildItemsPartner" />
      </EntityType>
      <EntityType Name="ChildItem">
        <Key>
          <PropertyRef Name="Id" />
        </Key>
        <Property Name="Id" Type="Edm.Int32" Nullable="false" />
        <Property Name="ParentId" Type="Edm.Int32" />
        <NavigationProperty Name="ParentItem" Relationship="MyNamespace_ParentItem_ParentItemPartner" ToRole="ParentItem" FromRole="ParentItemPartner" />
      </EntityType>
      <Association Name="MyNamespace_ChildItem_ChildItemsPartner">
        <End Type="MyNamespace.ChildItem" Role="ChildItems" Multiplicity="*" />
        <End Type="MyNamespace.ParentItem" Role="ChildItemsPartner" Multiplicity="0..1" />
      </Association>
      <Association Name="MyNamespace_ParentItem_ParentItemPartner">
        <End Type="MyNamespace.ParentItem" Role="ParentItem" Multiplicity="0..1" />
        <End Type="MyNamespace.ChildItem" Role="ParentItemPartner" Multiplicity="0..1" />
      </Association>
      <EntityContainer Name="Container" m:IsDefaultEntityContainer="true">
        <EntitySet Name="ParentItems" EntityType="MyNamespace.ParentItem" />
        <EntitySet Name="ChildItems" EntityType="MyNamespace.ChildItem" />
        <AssociationSet Name="MyNamespace_ChildItem_ChildItemsPartnerSet" Association="MyNamespace_ChildItem_ChildItemsPartner">
          <End Role="ChildItemsPartner" EntitySet="ParentItems" />
          <End Role="ChildItems" EntitySet="ChildItems" />
        </AssociationSet>
        <AssociationSet Name="MyNamespace_ParentItem_ParentItemPartnerSet" Association="MyNamespace_ParentItem_ParentItemPartner">
          <End Role="ParentItemPartner" EntitySet="ChildItems" />
          <End Role="ParentItem" EntitySet="ChildItems" />
        </AssociationSet>
      </EntityContainer>
    </Schema>
  </edmx:DataServices>
</edmx:Edmx>
```

I'm using `webApiOData` on the client:

```
breeze.config.initializeAdapterInstance('dataService', 'webApiOData', true);
```

The query which I'm execute looks like this:

```
breeze.EntityQuery().from('ParentItems').expand('ChildItems');
```

The server call returns the correct items:

```
{
  "odata.metadata":"http://example.com/api/$metadata#ParentItems","value":[
    {
      "odata.type":"MyNamespace.ParentItem","odata.id":"http://example.com/api/ParentItems(1)","ChildItems@odata.navigationLinkUrl":"http://example.com/api/ParentItems(1)/ChildItems","ChildItems":[
        {
          "odata.type":"MyNamespace.ChildItem","odata.id":"http://example.com/api/ChildItems(1)","ParentItem@odata.navigationLinkUrl":"http://example.com/api/ChildItems(1)/ParentItem","Id":1,"ParentItemId":1
        },{
          "odata.type":"MyNamespace.ChildItem","odata.id":"http://example.com/api/ChildItems(2)","ParentItem@odata.navigationLinkUrl":"http://example.com/api/ChildItems(2)/ParentItem","Id":2,"ParentItemId":1
        }
      ],"Id":1
    }
  ]
}
```

But the ChildItems property of the ParentItem entity is empty.

Edit: If I call `manager.getEntities()`after executing the query all parent and child items are returned.

Comment: I'm reading from my mobile, but the array doesn't look empty to me ` "ChildItems":[ { "odata.type":"MyNamespace.ChildItem","odata.id":"http://example.com/api/ChildItems(1)","ParentItem@odata.navigationLinkUrl":"http://example.com/api/ChildItems(1)/ParentItem","Id":1,"ParentItemId":1 },{ "odata.type":"MyNamespace.ChildItem","odata.id":"http://example.com/api/ChildItems(2)","ParentItem@odata.navigationLinkUrl":"http://example.com/api/ChildItems(2)/ParentItem","Id":2,"ParentItemId":1 } ]`

Comment: The child items are in the JSON result of the server request. But the ParentItem.ChildItems array of the Breeze entity is empty afterwards.